# How I can open other web site inside my Angular Component

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to make a web application that should open a web site inside a component then  the tool will act like selenium.
The senerio like this.
User type link and hit enter. Then we open the web page inside the component.  There is several ways to open a web page inside it like
Iframe, embed, object etc.
But here is the thing the web pages block me because of the `CORS POLICY`
So is there way to achive this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dom sanitizer and your cross domain should accept your request through iframe.

Here  is an example stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-158g4a

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer){}
  //https://www.google.com/  // does not work
  //https://angular.io/     // works fine
  url = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://angular.io/')
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

Comment: I want to open all web sites. Thats doesnt work for me

Comment: You cannot, at least not directly. Only way is to use a serverside proxy..